# "Unable to decrypt password" popup in Remote Desktop Connection Manager

Tags: remote-desktop, remote

I am using Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.2 and every time I click on *properties* on a VM of mine, I get a popup window:

> unable to decrypt password

How can I make this popup go away?

Answer (score 12):

Go to `Remote Desktop Connection Manager` -> `Edit` -> `Properties` -> `Logon Credentials` - `Clear the Password`.

Then click `Save` or `OK`.  You're good to go!

Comment: This does not apply with RDCMan 2.7

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to go through the servers one by one. see my reply below.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using a connection manager config file shared from another install/user, you can either retype the password in the properties and save, and/or select `store password in clear text`

Answer (score 8):

Open the *filename*.rdg file with an XML editor (like notepad++) and remove all the credentials that are in between the *<credentialsProfile>* & *</credentialsProfile>* metadata tags for each user that you get this error for. Then save the file.

When you open it the error message has gone. You can re-enter the existing domain, user and password then save over the top but if you have users in the error pop-up that you don't want displayed then you have no other choice.

It is a good idea to back up the file first in case you incorrectly edit the XML tags.

Cheers
V/-

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple connections setup you can use your favorite regex text editor and use the following regex and do a find/replace.

Find:

> ```
> \<password.*<\/password>
> ```

Replace:

> ```
> \<password\>\<\/password\>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Profile Management
Profiles
Delete any profile showing error message
Save RDG file and log back in

Answer (score 0):

remove all the profiles in  **Profile Manager** of **all** the root nodes  and recreate them again

Comment: this is not needed, you can just clear the usernames/password

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method:

1) Make a backup of the file, actually you should make a copy before open the .rdg file with version 2.7.

2) Open the .rdg file with **Notepad++**. Press **ctrl+h** to open the “Replace” popup window.

```
Find what:<password>.*</password>
Replace with: null
Search mode: Regular expression
```

3) Click “**Replace All**” button and save the file.

4) Open it with RDCMan 2.7. You should have no popup window anymore. Enjoy!

However, you will have to re-enter your password for these hosts.
Taken from [here](https://itgala.xyz/rdcman-there-were-problems-decrypting-some-credentials/)

Answer (score 0):

This problem on my machine was created by importing rdg file from my old PC.
I marked down all the servers which were complained about in the error message.
Repeat for each one:
right click on the server > properties > Logon credentials > delete username and password, click OK.

after you fix all of them, save the changes, reopen rdcman and it should not show you the error anymore.

Do not worry, passwords are actually remembered in the windows credentials, so they will remain "remembered".

Comment: How will they remain remembered when one moves from one machine to another? How can i copy the credentials from ona machine to another?