# "Unable to decrypt password" in Remote Desktop Connection Manager v2.2

Tags: windows, encryption, desktop, remote

I can log in as the administrator and access the servers just fine but the problem shows when I try to log as a user - then I get that message:

```
Unable to decrypt password
```

How can I fix it? Doing as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/344081/unable-to-decrypt-password-popup-in-remote-desktop-connection-manager) didn't help.